# Flex container with four divs, need three columns, second column with two rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-layout

For a section on a page, I am trying to display two rectangular divs stacked up between two square divs on either side as big as the height of the two stacked divs, inside these divs are img tags.

I am using this markup because on mobile I want to be able to have them on an un-wrapped flex row with an `overflow: hidden` parent so I can use a swipe code to translate the X-axis. I am having problems creating this layout for desktop with this markup using the flexbox (No grid, need to support IE11). Has anyone done this layout with this markup? Thanks.

```
 <div class="flex_container">
   <div class='flex_child square'>
     <img...>
   </div>
   <div class='flex-child rect'>
     <img...>
   </div>
   <div class='flex-child rect'>
     <img...>
   </div>
   <div class='flex-child square'>
     <img...>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image: Example by image]

Comment: Where is your CSS? What have tried?

Comment: Yes, many times, tried all sort of combinations; floats, display-inline as so on, easy to fix if I alter the markup by just nesting the two rectangular divs on another div with just `display: flex` on the `.flex_container`, I am just wondering if is posible at all with this markup

Comment: Flex won't work with this markup because you need two directions, and flex is good for a single direction only. What kind of support do you need for IE11? I would recommend using grid, then using a fallback for IE11.

Comment: I need to reproduce the image above in IE11 as well as other browsers, I tried the wrapper around the rect classes and it works fine in IE11, the thing is on mobile I need all divs on a row with an unwrapped flex so I can overflow the flex container and translate the x-axis

Comment: grid is better for this type of layout, IE10-11 support an old version of grid spec

Comment: Do you know how to code this on a grid layout compatible with IE11, that will gracefully, on mobile, align all divs on an unwrapped row without extra markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that this will be the main layout of your page you can try to set a fixed height and use column direction with flexbox:

```css
.flex_container {
  height: 100vh; /*adjust this value like you want*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.flex_child {
  background:purple;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:calc(100% / 3);
}
.square {
  flex:1 1 100%;
}
.rect {
  flex:1 1 47%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class='flex_child square'></div>
  <div class='flex_child rect  '></div>
  <div class='flex_child rect  '></div>
  <div class='flex_child square'></div>
</div>
```

And in case you want a better browser support you can use float/inline-block by slightly adjust the classes making the 2 squares at the start:

```css
.flex_container {
  height: 100vh; /*adjust this value like you want*/
}
.flex_child {
  background:purple;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:calc(100% / 3);
  height:100%;
}
.square:nth-child(1) {
  float:left;
}
.square:nth-child(2) {
  float:right;
}
.rect {
  display:inline-block;
  height:50%;
  vertical-align:top;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class='flex_child square'></div>
  <div class='flex_child square'></div>
  <div class='flex_child rect  '></div>
  <div class='flex_child rect  '></div>
</div>
```

In case you cannot also change the classes, use some negative margin to rectify the position of the last element:

```css
.flex_container {
  height: 100vh; /*adjust this value like you want*/
}
.flex_child {
  background:purple;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:calc(100% / 3);
  height:100%;
}
.square:first-child {
  float:left;
}
.square:last-child {
  float:right;
  margin-top:-50vh;
}
.rect {
  display:inline-block;
  height:50%;
  vertical-align:top;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class='flex_child square'></div>
  <div class='flex_child rect  '></div>
  <div class='flex_child rect  '></div>
  <div class='flex_child square'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It is a section of the page, I have tried it and have realised I ommited the fact that inside the flex childs there are images, so it does not scale well, I have updated the question

Comment: I managed to get it working by adding to the `flex_container`  `align-content: center`  and removing the calculated width on the `flex_child` and instead  of `flex: 1 1 ...` on the `.square` classes added `width: 35%` and `.rect`  `width: 30%`.  And of course had to set the height of the `flex_container` on resize with js. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Making some major assumptions about your content, but you can use absolute positioning to align things. Essentially you can pull the middle two elements out of the document flow and mimic stacking through positioning.

In this case, when above `767px`, the entire row is within the document flow. When below `767px`, we re-position the inner two elements and set the container to `justify-content: space-between` to provide the visual space.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex_container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.flex_item {
  flex: 1;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .flex_container {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }  

  .flex_item {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .square {
    flex: 0 1 33%;
  }
  
  .rect {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(100% / 3);
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 50%;
  }
  .rect.three {
    top: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="one flex_item square">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="two flex_item rect">
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="three flex_item rect">
    Three
  </div>
  <div class="four flex_item square">
    Four
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, be careful - this assumes you can control the height of the container and the dimensions of the content within. If not, this type of layout falls apart fairly easily. As stated in the other comments, if you want more structure and stability, it'd be better to wrap the inner elements with another flex element with `flex-direction: column`. Just know the risks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
   .flex_container{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      border: 1px solid red;

    }
    .flex_container2{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }  
    .flex-child{
      border: 1px solid blue;
     }
```

```html
 <div class="flex_container">
   <div class='flex_child square'>A</div>
   <div class="flex_container2">
       <div class='flex-child rect'>B</div>
       <div class='flex-child rect'>C</div>
   </div>
   <div class='flex-child square'>D</div>
 </div>
```

I think you need a second flex-container.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a second container to control the two `rect` it gets easier.
You can control the `height and width` of `square` to make them square, instead of dynamic width.

```css
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   height: 150px;
}
.container>*, .square {
  background-color: purple;
}

.flex-child {
    flex:1;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 2px
}

.square { flex-basis: 25%; }
.container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-basis: 50%
}
.container > * { 
  flex-basis: 50%; 
}
.container div:first-child {
 margin-right: 4px 
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-basis: 33.333%
  }
  .container div:first-child{
      margin: 0 0 4px 0
   } 
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class='flex-child square'></div>
   <div class='flex-child container'>
     <div class='rect'></div>
     <div class='rect'></div>
   </div>
   <div class='flex-child square'></div>
 </div>
```

Or: (click in `full page` to see changing)

```css
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   height: 150px;
}
.container>*, .square {
  background-color: purple;
}

.flex-child {
    flex:1;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 2px
}

.square { flex-basis: 25%; }
.container {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 33.333%
}
.container > * { 
  flex-basis: 50%; 
}
.container div:first-child {
 margin: 0 0 4px 0
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .square, .container>* {
     height: 100px;
    }
 .flex-container {
     height: auto;
     flex-direction: column; 
    }
   .rect {
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-basis: 50%
   }
   
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class='flex-child square'></div>
   <div class='flex-child container'>
      <div class='rect'></div>
      <div class='rect'></div>
   </div>
   <div class='flex-child square'></div>
 </div>
```